# Is it possible to use "Index" as column name in mysql

Tags: mysql, command-line

I have to create a database and table through the mysql command line as that is the only way to access the server. I tried creating a table with an index column (instead of the more common "ID" column), however it kept giving me an error.

I discovered that "Index" is a command in mysql, but I'd rather not have to change the name of the column for consistency with programs dealing that I've set up to deal with the database I'm creating.

**How do I stop the mysql command line from interpreting "Index" as a command?**

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/reserved-words.html or http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/identifiers.html

Comment: You can quote the column name, but please don't.  **You will hate yourself later.**  Trust us.

Comment: Also, the fact that you're using a column as an index should have no bearing on what you name the column.

Comment: Thanks Brian, that'll probably come in handy later. And Andy, I understand that, I'm in the middle of changing the programs I've written to use ID instead of Index, however knowing the quotation syntax may come in handy when that is not feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enclose the name in backquotes.  This allows reserved words to be used as column and tables names, as bad an idea as that is.

```
create table t (
    `index` int primary key,
    . . .
);
```

You will need to use the backquotes whenever you refer to the column.

Comment: Thanks, you're probably right it is a bad idea if I have to ensure its in backquotes every time as that'll lead to more possible errors.

Answer (score 2):

As @Gordon Linoff said, it's a bad idea.

Use "id" for the name of that column.